# git push -v hangs at writing objects at 6%

Tags: git

I am trying to push code from my workstation's Git repository's master branch to the server's repository.  It keeps hanging at the writing objects step at 6%.  Please help.  Thank you.

Workstation is running Git 2.17.1.windows.2 on Windows 10 while server is running Git 2.3.7 on Ubuntu.  Workstation and server are on the same LAN.  This is the very first push of a bunch of new files, although the project was created on the server originally and a previous pull worked.  Git protocol is being used (see git remote output at the bottom).

I followed the advice of this article
[Git writing objects hangs at 6%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971172/git-writing-objects-hangs-at-6)
and created a bundle file with "git bundle create foo.bundle --all".  It generated a file that is 1.72MB in size.

I tried raising the postBuffer to 512MB based on what this article said.
[Git Hangs when Writing objects to push on bitbucket-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705783/git-hangs-when-writing-objects-to-push-on-bitbucket-ubuntu)

git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

Didn't solve the problem.  The volume of upload is very small anyway.

I rebooted both my workstation and server.  Still didn't work.
[Git hangs while writing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887228/git-hangs-while-writing-objects)

The stuff that this article mentioned is not applicable, as I am using git protocol.  Maybe I should switch to ssh?
[Cannot push to remote git repo over ssh, stuck at "Writing objects: 11%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740601/cannot-push-to-remote-git-repo-over-ssh-stuck-at-writing-objects-11)

By the way, setting GIT_TRACE to true, 1 and 2 produced the same output.  Git's documentation does not explain how these different tracing levels are different.  Could someone please explain?
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

```
--- Output from git push command -----------------------------
set GIT_TRACE=true

git push -v

09:43:14.946332 exec_cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
09:43:14.948336 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git push -v
Pushing to git://192.168.4.24/Project
Looking up 192.168.4.24 ... done.
Connecting to 192.168.4.24 (port 9418) ... 192.168.4.24 done.
09:43:15.569819 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress
09:43:16.526970 exec_cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
09:43:16.528972 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress
Counting objects: 407, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (374/374), done.
Writing objects:   6% (25/407)

--- Server log /var/log/syslog -----------------------------

syslog:Feb  8 09:33:57 server git-daemon[1036]: Ready to rumble
syslog:Feb  8 09:43:18 server git-daemon[1612]: Connection from 192.168.4.121:55414
syslog:Feb  8 09:43:18 server git-daemon[1612]: Extended attributes (19 bytes) exist <host=192.168.4.24>
syslog:Feb  8 09:43:18 server git-daemon[1612]: Request receive-pack for '/Project'

--- git remote -v output -----------------------------

git remote -v

origin  git://192.168.4.24/Project (fetch)
origin  git://192.168.4.24/Project (push)

git remote show origin

* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git://192.168.4.24/Project
  Push  URL: git://192.168.4.24/Project
  HEAD branch: orig
  Remote branches:
    master tracked
    orig   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: "Maybe I should switch to ssh?"
The git protocol isn't recommended to use (https://twitter.com/hanno/status/1355200262319845379 this tweet and two earlier in the thread, boiling down to no security against MITM attacks or anything), ssh is nearly always the better choice - for anonymous clones, https is better.

Also, that post buffer you increased applies to HTTP only, which you aren't using, too.